# Dojo declarative onclick not triggering setter

Tags: dojo

Dojo 1.8

If I have a widget that has an overridden onclick setter:

```
// in mypackage/ClickableWidget
_setOnClickAttr: function( onClick ) {
    this.onClick = onClick;
    // handle the event...
}
```

...then it get's invoked just fine when I create the widget programattically:

```
new ClickableWidget({
     onClick: function() {
           alert('clicked');
     }
});
```

BUT... it seems when I create my widget declarativly:

```
<div data-dojo-type="mypackage/ClickableWidget">
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click">
        alert('clicked');
    </script>
</div>
```

...it doesn't trigger my overridden onclick setter.

Is this just a fact of dojo, or am I doing something wrong?

also, is there a better term to refer to what I am calling my "overridden setter"?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your "overriden onclick setter" ???

Comment: I was trying to write a component that will be used in a very generic way. When the user overrides the onclick handler I want to account for something else.
I think perhaps an alternate approach would be to use aspect advice for the onclick function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

Maybe the way you write the script tag is wrong:

Find this :

```
 <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">
```

Here's the link to the dojo-source: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/isFunction.html

My last guess. hope this helps.

Comment: This sets an onclick handler...but still doesn't seem to be invoking my overridden setter (_setOnClickAttr)

Comment: Look above, i've changed my Post

Comment: The event works...but still not triggering the overridden setter

Comment: And again -  hope this helps u out. Seems to be the right way to trigger

Comment: Yes! That did it. Thanks...

<div data-dojo-type="mypackage/ClickableWidget"> <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">        alert('click');</script></div>